# Want to use an array created in a method, for further use in another method

Tags: java, methods

I have a problem and the title actually sums it up perfectly. So i'll just go ahead and show you the code snippet.
So the methode generate, is generating an array, that is filled with numbers between 1 and 1000, including both. The length of the array is user input.
The next method, isPrime, is gonna conclude if its a prime number, so i can use those numbers with the true condition in another method. The generate method works but in isPrime i always get errors. If u can think of a better way, let me know please.

```
static int[] generate(int n) {
    int[] arr = new int[n+1];
    for(int x = 0; x <= n; x ++) {
        int number = (int) (Math.random()* 999)+1;
        arr[x] = number;
    }
    return arr;
}

static int isPrime(int p, final int q[]) {                           
    boolean itIs = true;
    //final int[] arr;

    for(int r = 0; r <= p; r++) {               // here it somehow states r is deadCode
        for(int j = 2; j < q[r]; j++) {             
            if(q[r]%j == 0) {                       
                itIs = false;                       
            }
        }
        return q[r];
    }

}
```

Comment: Probably because you return after the first iteration of the outer for loop. Also if this is an `isPrime()` method why are you returning an int? And why are you returning the element of the array you are testing?

Comment: Yeah i tried it already outside and it states that r isn't resolved to a variable. EDIT: When the itIs boolean is true, i want to make another method, which creates another array that takes the true array numbers.

Comment: When I plug this into my IDE it says nothing about dead code. It says that you are missing a return statement. But again I ask why are you return `q[r]` and not a boolean result?

Comment: Ah alright that is indeed a good question. I will try it out with a boolean return.

Comment: Also I would recommend only have `isPrime` accept a single int, and not an entire `Array`. Also you will find that you will need to utilize a `break` or `return` statement if `itIs` ever becomes false so the result will not get overridden

Comment: So now i need help again. How can i answer you guys in a way that i can put my code in it ? Or should i just change the code in the question ?

Answer (score 0):

First, create a method to check a value is prime:

```
public boolean isPrime(int value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < value / 2; i++) { // value / 2 is enough, doesn't need to check all values
        if (value % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then you check each value of array and put prime value to new array:

```
public int[] filterArray(int[] array) {
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (isPrime(array[i])) {
            intList.add(array[i]);
        }
    }
    Integer[] integerArray = intList.toArray(new Integer[intList.size()]);
    int[] intArray = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(integerArray);
    return intArray;
}
```

Then you get the filtered prime array.